# example concerning Lusin's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Is there any example satisfying the following:

$f$ is a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with lebesgue measure $\lambda$. For any subset $N\subseteq\mathbb{R}^N$ with $\lambda(N)=0$, $f|_{\mathbb{R}^N\setminus N}$ is not a continuous function?

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect there should be an example? The question could be improved by adding context, such as what related facts led you to think of the question and/or what you have already tried.

Comment: Perhaps the exponent of $\mathbb{R}$ should be $n$ throughout (rather than $N$ in two places)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My example is to take $f=\chi_X$. Now chose $X$ such that $X$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus X$ are dense and have positive measure in every interval. This is easy to arrange using well known constructions.

Comment: This goes further: namely, $f$ will be *nowhere* continuous. To answer the question as stated, $X$ can be a fat Cantor set.

Comment: Yes its, nowhere contiuous, you can get away with less just to answer the question.